# How to create a dataframe?

Tags: python, data-science

```
df4 = [] 
for i in (my_data.points.values.tolist()[0]): 
    df3 = pd.json_normalize(j) 
df4.append(df3)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4) 
df5.head()
```

When I run this code I get this error: `Must pass 2-d input. shape=(16001, 1, 3)`

Comment: What are `j` and `my_data`?

Comment: @Prasad Shinde. The df4.append(df3) should be inside for loop block condition.

Comment: I would do this df4 = [df3 for i in (my_data.points.values.tolist()[0])] 
df3 = pd.json_normalize(j) 
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4) 
df5.head()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

pd.json_normalize will change the json data to table format, but what you need to have is an array of dictionaries to be able to convert to a dataframe.

For example

```
dict_list=[
    {"id":1,"name":"apple","price":10},
    {"id":1,"name":"orange","price":20},
    {"id":1,"name":"pineapple","price":15},
]
df=pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

In your case

```
df4 = [] 
for i in (my_data.points.values.tolist()[0]): 
#    df3 = pd.json_normalize(j) since the structure is not mentioned, 
#    I'm assuming "i" as a dictionary which has the relevant row
     df4.append(i)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4) 
df5.head()
```